# How to convert char into int in a function?

Tags: c++

poziomy= char;
pionowy= digit; ( no problems with this one)

So I need to convert char into a digit in function but obviusly I cannot do char=int, so I dont know how to pass on the converted char into digit properly.

I guees i can do two functions but maybe there is an easier way?

I thought of making a new variable `poziomy_c` but I dont know how to pass it to `Ruch_gracza()`

```
int Convert_digit (int cyfra)
{
    switch (cyfra)
    {
        case 10: return 0;break;
        case 9: return 1;break;
        case 8: return 2;break;
        case 7: return 3;break;
        case 6: return 4;break;
        case 5: return 5;break;
        case 4: return 6;break;
        case 3: return 7;break;
        case 2: return 8;break;
        case 1: return 9;break;
    }
}

int Convert_letter (char literka)
{
   switch (literka)
   {
       case 'A': return 0; break;
       case 'B': return 1; break;
       case 'C': return 2; break;
       case 'D': return 3; break;
       case 'E': return 4; break;
       case 'F': return 5; break;
       case 'G': return 6; break;
       case 'H': return 7; break;
       case 'I': return 8; break;
       case 'J': return 9; break;
   }
}

void Conwert(int &pionowy, char poziomy)
{
     pionowy=Convert_digit(pionowy);

     int poziomy_c;
     poziomy_c=Convert_letter (poziomy);
}

void Ruch_gracza1 (int plansza[10][10])
{
    int pionowy ;
    char poziomy;
    cout << "wprowadz wspolrzedne pola na ktorym lezy pion który chcesz ruszyc ( w pionie , potem w poziomie)" << endl;
    cin >> pionowy >> poziomy;
    Conwert (pionowy,poziomy);
    cout << pionowy << endl;
    cout << poziomy << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you have a char variable `ch` which contains a digit from `'0'` to `'9'` then simply `ch - '0'` is the integer value of that digit. Is that what you wanted? It's a bit hard to tell from your question.

Comment: If you post code here you should write the code with english variable and function names and text. One important part for understanding the code are variable and function names.

Comment: A c-type conversion will do that:  char b; funtion((int) b) <== this converses the char b to interger. A char is indeed a 1-byte integer.

Comment: @t.niese I think the policy here is that variable names can be in any ASCII-friendly language as long as the question title and body are in English: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/2602718

Comment: Very unclear. Is the issue that you don't pass 2nd param by reference: `void Conwert(int &pionowy, char poziomy)`?

Comment: @scohe001 It is for sure not a requirement to write the code in english, like it is not required to use any meaningfull names for function/variables at all. But beeing able to read and therefore understand the meaning of the names help to understand for what they are used, help to determin what values they should hold, and therfore make it easier to find errors. For simple problems like this it might not be relevant. But also for others that seek for an answer a question with code that is in a foreign language might not be as helpful as one in english.

Answer (score 5):

You can use char arithmetic to make this a whole lot easier. Since 'A' to 'Z' will be contiguous in ASCII/Unicode, you can do `literka - 'A'` to get how far `literka` is from `A` (which is what your switch is doing):

```
int Convert_letter (char literka) {
    if(!std::isalpha(literka)) { return literka; } // Not a letter
    return std::toupper(literka) - 'A';
}
```

Or if you want a more robust solution to cover even less common character encodings:

```
int Convert_letter (char literka) {
    if(!std::isalpha(literka)) { return literka; } // Not a letter
    std::string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    return std::distance(std::begin(alphabet), std::find(std::begin(alphabet), std::end(alphabet), literka));;
}
```

`Convert_digit` will look similar (except with `std::isdigit` instead of `std::isalpha`).

Comment: And for EBCDIC?

Comment: @Jarod Do you have a suggestion for a more portable solution for such a system?

Comment: `std::distance(std::begin(alphabet), std::find(std::begin(alphabet), std::end(alphabet), letter));`.

Comment: Now to continue in nit-picking, [`isapha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) has bad interface, and require to be wrapped :/ and it is also locale dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

```
char c = 'B';

int digit = c - 'A';
 
return digit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some knowledge about the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and data type in C++.
Simply, a char is an integer from -128 ... 127. If you declare a char variable name **ch** like this:

```
char ch = 'B';
```

C++ will understand that **ch = 66** (look at ASCII table). So that we can do arithmetic operator with **ch** like an integer variable.

```
ch - 'A'; // result 1, because 'A' = 65
ch - 65;  // same result with ch - 'A'
```

Finally, you can write your function like this:

```
int functionChar2Int(char x){
  return x - 'A';
}
```

Comment: *"a char is an integer from -128 ... 127"*. No, `char` might be signed or not, so only 0-127 range is guaranteed.

Comment: ASCII is not the only mapping, there exist EBCDIC for example, and `ch - 'A'` won't give expected result.

Comment: Thank you for your comment about EBCDIC.